# change the navigation bar url from yii2 without redirecting

Tags: yii2

I would like to change the navigation url that will be send to the browser. The problem is the browser is receiving the route to the action that render the view; I don't want that and don't want to redirect.

Is there any way?

Comment: show a pratical example, please

Comment: I don't get what you mean by pratical example. Ex: I request the action site/profane in the browser navigation bar there will be www/music/web/index.php?r=site%2Fprofane but what I want is to change that url to www/music/web/index.php?r=site%2Findex even after loading the page from the action www/music/web/index.php?r=site%2Fprofane

Comment: Do you mean change the url placed  in a certain position in navbar?.. but this url remain the same or for every request change?.

Comment: Do you mean change the url placed in a certain position in navbar? Yes but not remaining the same for every request.

Comment: Then you want the receiver show in a specific place of the  navbar the sender url?

Comment: I don't get it what you are saying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96861/discussion-between-aidonsnous-and-scaisedge).

Comment: Have you see the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 Url::remember();
```

for remeber the current url before you call the destination.  Then in the destination  page you can change,  in you navbar, the url you need obtining the  URL remembered in the following way:

```
 $url = Url::previous();
```

Comment: Does setting the variable $url has will automatically change the the url of the page that is being load in the browser ? I tried it not working.

Comment: This save an url  (the current)  before you  navigate to another url.

Comment: In the destionation page You can recall the " remenbered" url  and apply to the navbar url

Comment: Or better in your layout, in the navbar widget you can get  the remembered  url and assign to the link position you need

Comment: I don't have navbar in my layout; I removed it because I don't really need it